# find the intersection of files on OSX

Tags: macos, file-search

I have 4 files of text. I would like to find what's the same in these files and output it to another file. kinda like an intersection of 4 sets.

Content looks like this:

```
.somecss
.anothercss
.blabla
```

How can I achieve this? I am on a mac.

Comment: Interesting hints here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/111495/how-to-diff-multiple-files-across-directories

Comment: Do you want the set of lines that is found in all 4 files?  Are the files already sorted?  How should duplicate lines be handled?